# How to Create an index of a key in a map or item in a list in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing

The following questions refer to my example.

1. How do I create an index for the ids in idsAndNames map?

   I want to search these numbers: 7065362, 7064458, 7065003, 7064286...
2. How do I create an index for the strings in subTargets list?

   I want to search these strings: ALL, ACTION, DRAMA...

**My example**:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsd910d41ad9"),
    "targets" : {
        "Superheroes" : {
            "idsAndNames" : {
                "7065362" : "Doctor Strange",
                "7064458" : "Dr. Manhattan",
                "7065003" : "Captain Atom",
                "7064286" : "Hulk"
            },
            "subTargets" : [ 
                "ALL",
                "ACTION",
                "DRAMA"
            ]
        }
        "BestSuperheroes" : {
            "idsAndNames" : {
                "7065362" : "Superman",
                "7064458" : "Thor",
                "7065003" : "Professor X",
                "7064286" : "Batman"
            },
            "subTargets" : [ 
                "ALL",
                "SCIFI",
                "CHICKFLICKS"
            ]
        }        
    }
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to create an index maybe you should review your schema, changing it to something like:

```
...
"Superheores" : [
 {
    "id": "7065362",
    "name": "Doctor Strange"

 }]
```

So you can use `db.collection.ensureIndex({'targets.Superheroes.id': 1});`. You won't be able to create an effective index if you have dynamic key names.

And for the text, you could try [the text search index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/).

Comment: Sounds like a good solution to my problem.
If I had id numbers instead of strings, is there an easy way to add an index on them? 

            "subTargets" : [ 
                123,
                124,
                125
            ]

Or should I use the same method and add another key value for the Superheroes list you created?
Here I would have duplicates, but it's not so horrible..

Comment: If the value is just an array of numbers you don't need to create a similar structure, just use them directly in an array.
More details on creating multi-key indexes [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/)